# публикация веб приложения на сервере IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly, публикация-приложений

**Мои действия,**

- поставила на релиз,
- почистила и сгенерировала проект,
  ==>там было указано установите `wasm-tools-net6`, ок
- установила и нажала публиковать,
- установила на сервер, не сработало нашла где то по своим ошибкам там тут

```
<WasmEnableSIMD>true</WasmEnableSIMD>
<WasmEnableExceptionHandling>true</WasmEnableExceptionHandling>
<PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>
```

тоже не помогло, потом видела, что ===>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тоже не помогло,

писалось что то типа "/" не находит, вообщем нашла, что оказывается надо менять в индексе `<base href="/app/" />` поменяла, и каждый раз чистила и и публиковала снова. не работаетчто я пропустила?

[в этом примере все так гладко](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116982/how-do-i-publish-a-blazor-asp-net-app-in-iis), я все удалила точно как он сделала, все равно не работает, ну пожалуйста помогите, я сутки уже не разберусь

а да, еще было сказано где то, что поменять место расположения
`C:\inetpub` в документации `IIS`сейчас у меня открывает страницу и показывает как страница навигация с ссылками на мои страницы, перехожу на разор страницу выдает ошибку типа добавьте `MIME` , ...

у меня вопрос вот я добавила в индекс что мол не просто слеш ищи а `app`, а где потом это указывать, типа стартап класса, у меня ведь только класс `Program`

Приложение Blazor Web Assembly

Может кто уже устанавливал веб приложение на Сервер ISS подскажите туториал ясный эффективный и понятный, и чтоб работало, учиться ведь откудато нужно, в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) то что пишут, пытаюсь повторить но будто разваливается не собравшись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`веб конфиг`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!--это по умолчанию добавленные теги-->
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>

    <!--я прочитала документации и и потребность и добавила комментарии того, что понятно и объясненно корректно-->
    <!-- for PublishIISAssets ===> doc: If the SDK doesn't generate the file, for example, in a standalone Blazor WebAssembly app at /bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/publish/wwwroot or bin\Release\{TARGET FRAMEWORK}\browser-wasm\publish, depending on which version of the SDK is used and where the {TARGET FRAMEWORK} placeholder is the target framework, set the <PublishIISAssets> property to true in the project file (.csproj). Usually for standalone WebAssembly apps, this is the only required setting to move a custom web.config file and prevent transformation of the file by the SDK.-->
    <PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>
    <!-- for PublishTrimmed ===> Trims unused libraries to reduce the deployment size of an app when publishing a self-contained executable. For more information, see Trim self-contained deployments and executables. Available since .NET 6 SDK.-->
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
    <!-- for BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport ===> A data file is included to make timezone information correct. If the app doesn't require this feature, consider disabling it by setting the BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport MSBuild property in the app's project file to false:-->
    <BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>false</BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyPreserveCollationData>false</BlazorWebAssemblyPreserveCollationData>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>

<!--по этому файлу возможно ===> кто еще что добавляет для хорошей практики, а может наоборот тут надо удалить лишнее...-->
```

еше, обратите внимание, если у вас установлены следующие пакеты
[скачайте sdk тут](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) найдите нужную вам версию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`VS` важно открыть от имени администратора, я также почистила все папки релиз в проекте и
опубликовала пакет, разместила на сервер в папку по умолчанию `C:\inetpub`, и добавила новый сайт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом перешла в визуал студио и опубликовала Server Web IIS предварительно подключившись к сайту, и посмотрела все ли загрузилось

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там можно было использовать пароль и логин, а можно просто, я не настраивала эту часть

далее опубликовала и разместила на сервере, то есть в папке, которую читает сервер, настроила `порт` оставила `localhost` (хотя протестировала оба варианта и путьАйПи и локалХост)

а, и еще в части `Паннель и Конфигурация ===> Программы ===> слева меню`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и затем popUp открывается и там все, что касалось `IIS`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там важно дать разрешение для IIS,

я также перезагрузила комп, чтоб точно присвоить все изменения, а еще можно почистить браузер, тк там есть `CashStorage` туда может быть загруженны неверные пути и пустые переменные `правила`